# Fujitsu A544 Removing the optical drive?

Tags: laptop, optical-drive

I recently purchased a Fujitsu A544 laptop,
I'm trying to remove the optical drive in the laptop and
replace it with an hdd caddy, but I can't find a way how to do it.
I searched extensively in google and youtube for guidance, in fruitless effort.
Help and guidance is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You couldn't find a way to remove the optical drive from the laptop , or to install the new hdd on the hdd caddy , or to do it all ? anyway here is a link on how to install the hdd on the optical drive [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=kKVwymFlQD0) , removing the optical drive needs attention because there are always some screws hidden somewhere , i couldn't find a disassembly manual for your model ,so be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One screw and it slides out.

The manual can be [downloaded here](http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Download/ShowDescription.asp?Info=FTS&LNID=48&SoftwareGUID=EAB884FF-FB6C-4C41-8E5A-19EE110D0607&lng=COM#ABG)

The rest of your manuals can be found [using this page](http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Manuals/Index.asp)

[image]

Comment: Your Welcome! Have a Great Year.